# Power Pivot: Average by group using many-to-many table relationship

Tags: excel, dax, powerpivot

I have three tables in Power Pivot. Pupils, Baselines and Reports. The Pupils table connects to the Reports and Baselines tables via a One to Many relationship as shown below.

[image]

The Reports table has each pupil listed multiple times for each subject they have a report in. They are also listed multiple times in the Baselines table for each baseline score they have. What I want to accomplish is to create a measure that calculates the average baseline score in each subject. So take all pupils who have a maths report, I want to know the average baseline score in maths.

I tried the following measure:
`Av Baseline:=AVERAGEX( CALCULATETABLE( Baselines, Baselines[Type] = "Overall" ),  Baselines[Average]  )`

However the above when used in a pivot table produces the same result for all subjects, so the filter context is not being applied. I keep hearing people using bridge tables, which does add a ton of data and are not very efficient so I hope to avoid those if at all possible.

I have provided some example data with the desired output table, hope that helps?

[image: Pupils] [image: Reports] [image: Baselines] [image: Result pivot table]

Comment: How are the Baseline scores associated to a given subject? I think it would be better if you posted 3 small tables, 10 rows' worth of data or so, together with expected results.

Comment: If you want to apply a filter to the Baselines[Type], then your `Baselines[Type] = "Overall"` removes it. You have 1 value for each Pupil-Baseline in Baselines table and it is `Baselines[Average]` , right? If it is so, then `AVERAGEX( Baselines, 
 Baselines[Average])` is enough in case of usage Baselines slicer or filter.

Comment: Please provide full columns of tables and also your pivot table report. We need to know how you filter the fact tables...  It seems clear that your filter doesn't reach destination table due to filter direction.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please test this:
Note: I hope Your Pupils table has a column called [Subject Code] It is not clear from your shared data.

Version - 1

```
Av Baseline :=
AVERAGEX (
    VALUES ( Pupils[Subject Code] ),
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( Baselines[Average] ),
        CALCULATETABLE ( Baselines, Baselines[Type] = "Overall" )
    )
)
```

Version - 2

```
Av Baseline =
VAR Combin =
    SUMMARIZE (
        Baselines,
        Baselines[Type],
        Pupils[Subject Code],
        Baselines[Result]
    )
VAR Combinfiltered =
    FILTER ( Combin, Baselines[Type] = "Overall" )
VAR Result =
    CALCULATE ( AVERAGE ( Baselines[Result] ), Combinfiltered )
RETURN
    Result
```